# Insert line jump according to a condition, Bash Ubuntu

Tags: bash, text, sed, edit

I have the following text to edit in ubuntu's bash:

```
Fo, 68

Fo, 55**Fm**,   328

Fv, 273

Fv/Fm,  0.832

PAR,
    
TEMP,

Fs, 65

Fm',    91

èPS2,   0.286,
```

The text continues but the above is the fundamental unity.

I want to insert a line jump before the first Fm (in the second line, not means that it is only in the second one), so I tried with:

```
sed -e 's/Fm/\nFm/g'
```

But this command insert a line jump after the bar / of Fv/Fm too. I want to avoid that because is my interest to conserve the Fv/Fm as it. In other words, I need to conserve Fv/Fm in that form.

Thank you!

Comment: there are 3x copies of the string `Fm` in your sample output (and I'm assuming more in the complete file) ... how do you determine which of these `Fm` instances to process?  are you looking to process just the **first** occurrence of `Fm`? are you looking to process all occurrences in a line with the pattern `Fo,##Fm,###`? something else?  also, you mention wanting to add `\n` **after** the `Fm` but your `sed` replacement pattern (`\nFm`) says to add the `\n` **before** the `Fm` ... can you update the question with a clarification?

Comment: Please edit your question with input and desired output. Is the input actually double spaced? What do you mean by 'line jump'?

Comment: Use a more specific regular expression that only matches the cases you want to replace.

Comment: @dawg desired output is what markp-fuso answered. Thanks him, and thanks you for your recommendation. By line jump I mean line jump, or  \n. What you english guys refers to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- want to insert a `\n` **before** the string `Fm` if ...
- the character preceding the `Fm` is a number (`[0-9]`)
- there may be more than one replacement to perform in the entire file (ie, don't limit replacement to just the first occurrence)

Sample input (last 3 lines added to demonstrate assumptions):

```
$ cat x
Fo, 68
Fo, 55Fm,   328                # insert '\n' before this 'Fm'
Fv, 273
Fv/Fm,  0.832                  # leave this 'Fm' alone
PAR,
TEMP,
Fs, 65
Fm',    91                     # leave this 'Fm' alone
èPS2,   0.286,
Fo, 33Fm,   328                # insert '\n' before this 'Fm'
Fo, 9XFm,   328                # leave this 'Fm' alone
Fo, 97Fm,   328                # insert '\n' before this 'Fm'
```

One `sed` idea:

```
$ sed  '/[0-9]Fm/ s/Fm/\nFm/' x
Fo, 68
Fo, 55
Fm,   328                      # '\n' inserted before this 'Fm'
Fv, 273
Fv/Fm,  0.832                  # leave this 'Fm' alone
PAR,
TEMP,
Fs, 65
Fm',    91                     # leave this 'Fm' alone
èPS2,   0.286,
Fo, 33
Fm,   328                      # '\n' inserted before this 'Fm'
Fo, 9XFm,   328                # leave this 'Fm' alone
Fo, 97
Fm,   328                      # '\n' inserted before this 'Fm'
```